# Grouping data and calculating totals for new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains data to be used in calculations. I have to group rows based on 3 columns and then calculate the totals and plug the totals into a formula.

formula = -(totalvalue - totalFP)/ totalquantity
where totalvalue is the sum of quantity column
totalvalue is the sum of the value column
totalFP is the sum of each price*quantity

My data looks like this(I simplified the numbers a bit):

```
DealType  StartDate  Commodity                 FixedPrice Quantity Value
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            1.0       10      10
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            2.0       10      10
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            3.0       10      10
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    1.0       10      10
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    2.0       10      10
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    3.0       10      10
```

After grouping it should be like this:

```
DealType  StartDate  Commodity                 FixedPrice Quantity Value TotalFP FloatPrice
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            1.0       10      10      10       
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            2.0       10      10      20
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            3.0       10      10      30
                                                           30      30      60       1.0
DealType  StartDate  Commodity                 FixedPrice Quantity Value TotalFP FloatPrice
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    1.0       10      10      10 
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    2.0       10      10      20
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    3.0       10      10      30
                                                           30      30      60       1.0
```

the final result should be:

```
DealType  StartDate  Commodity                 FixedPrice Quantity Value FloatPrice
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            1.0       10      10       1.0
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            2.0       10      10       1.0
Sell      01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2]            3.0       10      10       1.0
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    1.0       10      10       1.0
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    2.0       10      10       1.0
Buy       01Dec2023  [stock1, stock2, stock3]    3.0       10      10       1.0
```

This is the code I have:

```
 # Grouping by 'Commodity', 'StartDate', and 'Deal Type'
    grouped_df = df.groupby(['Commodity', 'StartDate', 'DealType'])

    # Calculating total MTMValue, fixedstrikeprice and quantity for each group
    total_values = grouped_df.agg({'MTMValue': 'sum', 'FixedPriceStrike': 'sum', 'Quantity': 'sum'})

    # Calculating FloatPrice using the provided formula
    total_values['FloatPrice'] = -(total_values['MTMValue'] - (total_values['FixedPriceStrike'] * total_values['Quantity'])) / total_values['Quantity']

    # Merging the FloatPrice back to the original DataFrame based on the group columns
    df = pd.merge(df, total_values['FloatPrice'], how='left', on=['Commodity', 'StartDate', 'DealType'])
```

but this throws an error on the second line 'unhashable type list' and i am unsure how to fix. Is there a better solution than the approach I have?

I also tried this, but got the same error:

```
 df['FloatPrice'] = grouped_df.apply(lambda group: -(group['MTMValue'].sum() - (group['FixedPriceStrike'] * group['Quantity']).sum()) / group['Quantity'].sum()).reset_index(level=[0, 1, 2], drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df.assign(Commodity = lambda d: [tuple(i) for i in  d.Commodity])
df1.merge(df1
   .groupby(['DealType', 'StartDate', 'Commodity'])
   .apply(lambda _ : - (_.Value.sum() - (_.FixedPrice*_.Quantity).sum())/ _.Quantity.sum())
   .rename('FloatPrice')
   .reset_index())

  DealType  StartDate                 Commodity  ...  Quantity  Value  FloatPrice
0     Sell  01Dec2023          (stock1, stock2)  ...        10     10         1.0
1     Sell  01Dec2023          (stock1, stock2)  ...        10     10         1.0
2     Sell  01Dec2023          (stock1, stock2)  ...        10     10         1.0
3      Buy  01Dec2023  (stock1, stock2, stock3)  ...        10     10         1.0
4      Buy  01Dec2023  (stock1, stock2, stock3)  ...        10     10         1.0
5      Buy  01Dec2023  (stock1, stock2, stock3)  ...        10     10         1.0
```

Comment: This still returns the same error for me

Comment: @iBeMeltin ensure that all grouping variables are hashable. Ie if list convert to tuple